# Why can't the image be displayed on img tag in html using php document root on windows 10 using wamp64?

Tags: php, html

I can't seem to display the image.
I'm writing this code in document_root/admin and the img file is located on document_root/img/food

When I tried using this code

```
<img src="<?php echo htmlentities("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/".$row['food_img']); ?>" width="100px"></img>
```

The HTML from the PHP shows this
[image]

This is the output
[image]

before you bash me, I'm just a student.. still trying to learn PHP and the CRUD for image file

Comment: `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` will only point to the correct place if you create a Virtual Host for this site See[The need for Virtual Host](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)

Comment: Why are you trying to use a file system path, in a place where you should be using a URL instead? (If you are not aware of the difference, go read up on it!)